# Run a python script from java: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, python, process, processbuilder

Before you report this as a duplicate, understand that I have now spent a few hours looking over similar questions from a multitude of different websites, many being from here. They do not explain the solution well enough for me to take their answers and apply them to my own problem. If you still feel the itch to report this, go for it. All you'll be doing is preventing me from learning to code better.

I am attempting to call a python script and pass it 5 arguments. I have tried a few different ways to do this and believe the process builder route is my best option. However, I have a few questions as it does not seem to be the right code:

1. Do I need to be giving process builder a path to an executable, or can I just give it a path to the normal .py file?
2. Do I need to collect the output from the python file?

If there are any other aspects of the problem I am not seeing, please let me know. My code looks correct compared to others' on the internet doing the same thing. It is listed below:

```
 private void runPython(String pythonPath, HashMap<String, String> map){
     pythonPath = "C:/Users/Carlos/PycharmProjects/autoHTML/javaToExcel.py";

     try {

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(pythonPath + "/" + "python", pythonPath, map.get("Driver Advances"), map.get("Driver Loans"),
                map.get("Escrow Fund"), map.get("Maintenance Fund"), map.get("Highway Use tax - 2290"));

        Process p = pb.start();

    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Python error");
    }
}
```

if there is any code you want or any questions you need answered to help me out, please let me know.

Comment: Perhaps you want `"python.exe"` instead of `"python"`?

Comment: @JohnGordon still not working

Comment: The first argument to ProcessBuilder ends up being `C:/Users/Carlos/PycharmProjects/autoHTML/javaToExcel.py/python.exe`.  Surely that isn't right.

Comment: I would agree. But, after viewing other solutions to similar issues on SO, many had their absolute path + /python on the end of it. Really not sure where to go from here, and I'm honestly surprised that calling python scripts from java isn't a common procedure as there aren't many resources discussing it on the internet @JohnGordon

Comment: Where is `python.exe` actually installed on your system?  Try using that path instead of pythonPath for the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

To create an operating system processes, you can use ProcessBuilder which takes 2 arguments:

- The process to run, here this is the path to your Python executable (a.k.a: "C:/Users/Carlos/PycharmProjects/autoHTML/javaToExcel.py/python.exe" or something similar).
- The arguments to pass to your process:

  - The path to your python script and its own arguments.

You can try with:

```java
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
    "C:/Users/Carlos/PycharmProjects/autoHTML/javaToExcel.py/python.exe",
    pythonPath,
    map.get("Driver Advances"),
    map.get("Driver Loans"),
    map.get("Escrow Fund"),
    map.get("Maintenance Fund"),
    map.get("Highway Use tax - 2290"));
```

Comment: I appreciate the response. So it seems that the issue is definitely with the "command" I am supplying process builder. But, adding python.exe did not work. Any idea what the issue could be? My only idea is that the intellij IDE can not look into that file/environment for some reason. Let me know what you think